# Create a complex CSS shape (speaking bubble)

Tags: css, border, shapes, css-shapes

What would be your best option or method to create a shape as seen in the attachment link full CSS and is that possible anyway??

I did research and testing with CSS parallelogram e.g. but not with any good succes yet.

See the shape here -->> http://tinypic.com/r/352ge3b/6

[image: complex speech bubble]

Comment: What have you got so far? - it's a good idea to provide as much information as possible about whatever progress you have made.

Comment: You'd have to use several elements and lots of CSS3 transforms, but it's possible. Have a go yourself first, and when you run into problems, come back ;)

Comment: You are right! I will share the code later on. Not on my working station right now.

Comment: Also a interesting question is; What would you guys do? Is it wourth putting all the effort in making this shape in CSS. Or would you just use images (via sprite) resulting in making extra requests..

Comment: Yes, you can do it. And quite easily actually. I'll make a demo now. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this thing that it could be done with just one element - and it can be done, I just don't think it's exactly the best solution to do it like this.

## [***DEMO***](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/hzcwl)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='speech-bubble'>Hello!</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  margin: .5em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 10em; height: 4em;
  border-radius: .25em;
  transform: rotate(-4deg) rotateY(15deg);
  background: #629bdd;
  font: 2em/4 Century Gothic, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.speech-bubble:before, .speech-bubble:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
}
.speech-bubble:after {
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transform: rotate(2deg) translate(.35em, -.15em) scale(1.02);
  background: #f4fbfe;
}
.speech-bubble:before {
  border: solid 0 transparent;
  border-right: solid 3.5em #f4fbfe;
  border-bottom: solid .25em #629bdd;
  bottom: .25em; left: 1.25em;
  width: 0; height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg) skewX(75deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, what you're looking for, but I was playing around with CSS3's perspective and rotate and made this:

```
body {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 50px;
    padding:10px;
    perspective:150;
    -webkit-perspective:150;
}

.inner {
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding:50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #80BFFF;
    transform: rotateY(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(10deg);
    box-shadow: -4px -4px 0px #3399FF;
}

.inner:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 20px;
    top: 115px;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #80BFFF transparent transparent #80BFFF;
}
```

That's my HTML stuff

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Yay!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this one and reply my thoughts.