# :before element not displaying outside div speech-bubble

Tags: html, css

This is probably going to be a quick fix I just don't understand what's going on.

I saw this answer to a question [Create a complex CSS shape (speaking bubble)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877037/create-a-complex-css-shape-speaking-bubble/14882535#14882535) and I wanted to make something like it. So in my attempt for some reason the :before pseudo element is not displaying outside the "parent" div. I'm trying to make it look like a speech bubble so I need the element to display outside the div.

Here's my code

HTML

```
<div class="image">
    <img class="test" src="http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/322/e/2/e292b11555866aec8666ded2e63ee541-d4gl4vg.png" alt="leopard" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
 background-color: #333;
}
.image {
    position:relative;
    width:360px;
    background:orange;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.image:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  content: '';
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 0 transparent;
  top: 50px; left: -1.25em;
  width: 5em; height: 1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg) skewX(75deg);
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 5px #000000, -3px 0px 2px 6px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000, -3px 0px 2px 6px #000;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 5px #000000, -3px 0px 2px 6px #000;
}

.test {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here is a codepen. [Demo](http://codepen.io/johnsonjo4531/pen/nHxzi)

Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove overflow: hidden and add your `border-radius` to both `.image` and `.test`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bFElG

Answer (score 1):

If you have `overflow: hidden` on the image element, nothing will be shown outside of it. That's what `hidden` does.

You can:

- Remove the `overflow: hidden`, and change the image to a sized div element, and use the image as a background image, or
- Wrap the image in another element, and apply the :before styling to the wrapper element

Comment: Well I forgot about that.  That was pretty dumb.  I tried doing the second bullet, but it didn't work. [codepen](http://codepen.io/johnsonjo4531/pen/skaqb) Any help?